# Stuck trying to retrieve images from a list - scraping webpage

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

I have some VERY basic knowledge in scraping webpages however am stuck on one thing.   I am using php simple html dom and am struggling to get the image from within each of the 'li' tags.

```
<ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <img src="www.webpage.com/oH7oCOEhQABNAE2hnTQ.jpg" draggable="false">
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="www.webpage.com/ooabIAkbadaaIEJnkka.jpg" draggable="false">
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="www.webpage.com/bEQLaooknOAEQlaihna.jpg" draggable="false">
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can easily get the 1st image by using this code:

```
    $td = $d1->find('ul.slides li img',0);
    if ($td != null){
        $slides_image1 = trim($td->src) ;
    }
```

But haven't been able to work out how to get any of the other images.  Obviously I need to go to the 1st 'li' and retrieve that image, then the 2nd 'li' and retrieve that image, etc...   Can anyone help at all ?

Comment: Could you give us more source code? I guess that `$d1` is a `DOMDocument`. Then you could just do `$d1->getElementsByTagName("img")` and would get all img-tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the simple HTML DOM parser, rather than passing 0 to `find` which says return the first instance, miss this value out and it returns all instances.  So use the return value in a `foreach()`...

```
$slides_image = [];
foreach ($d1->find('ul.slides li img') as $td) {
    $slides_image[] = trim($td->src) ;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nigel, thanks for your quick reply.  That looks great.  Just one thing - I am inserting all of the images into a MySQL database with each image in it's own field (named slides_image1 ... to ...slides_image10).  How would I then amend the mysql_query to ensure that the correct images are inserted into the correct fields in the database ?

Comment: Depending on how your inserting it, but at the simplest case - `$slide_image1` will now be `$slides_image[0]` (as arrays are 0 based) through to `$slide_image10` will be `$slides_image[9]`.

Comment: Thanks Nigel, that worked well !   Appreciate your help.